# Mostrar div após certa quantia de digitos em input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textFind').click(function () {
            $('.pesquisas').toggle(200);
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (a) {
            return function (e) {
                return ~$(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase());
            }
        });
        $("[name=q]").on("input", function () {
            $(".opcao").hide();
            $(".opcao:contains('" + this.value + "')").show();
        });
    });
```

```css
.pesquisas {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="q" class="search-text" placeholder="Procurar..." autocomplete="off" id="textFind">
<div class="pesquisas" id="pesquisas">
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de clientes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de fornecedores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo fornecedor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de produtos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo produto</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

No código acima, ao clicar no `input` de pesquisa a minha `div` 'pesquisa' aparece, como eu faço para que ela apareça apenas depois de digitar mais que uma letra no `input`? Por exemplo, ao invés de quando eu clicar já aparecer a lista, só deve aparecer, quando eu digitar as letras 'ag', a `div` contendo `agenda`? E mais, como faço para que quando eu clicar fora da div `pesquisas` ela não apareça mais (`display: none`), e não só quando eu clique no input novamente?

OBS. A intenção de cada botão `<a>...</a>` é que sejam clicáveis. Posteriormente terão `href='algum lugar'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira é executar o evento no `keyup` e verificar o tamanho do valor do input.

Para esconder a `div` é só colocar o evento no `document` e verificar ao clicar se o evento contém a `div #pesquisas`, se não tiver, quer dizer que o click foi fora do elemento

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textFind').on('keyup', function(){
            if($(this).val().length >= 1){
              $('.pesquisas').show('slide');
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", function(e) {
            var div = document.querySelector("#pesquisas");
            var fora = !div.contains(e.target);
            if (fora){
                $('.pesquisas').hide('slide');
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (a) {
            return function (e) {
                return ~$(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase());
            }
        });
        $("[name=q]").on("input", function () {
            $(".opcao").hide();
            $(".opcao:contains('" + this.value + "')").show();
        });
    });
```

```css
.pesquisas {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="q" class="search-text" placeholder="Procurar..." autocomplete="off" id="textFind">
<div class="pesquisas" id="pesquisas">
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de clientes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de fornecedores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo fornecedor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de produtos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo produto</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apenas alterei para `$('.pesquisas').show('slide');` pois a cada dois caracteres digitados a `div` escondia.

Comment: Como a intenção dos botões `<a>...</a>` são ser clicáveis, ao clicar em alguma opção a div `pesquisas` irá sumir e não encaminhará para a página definida usando a função `$('#textFind').focusout(function()`.

Comment: @Rafael Fiz a alteração pra pegar o click fora da div

Answer (score 2):

Existem muitas maneiras de fazer isto, uma delas é a seguinte, colocar um evento de [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) para quando for digitado algo no campo mostrar a lista e já ir filtrando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valor = $('#textFind');
  valor.on('input', function() {
    if(valor.val().length > 1) $('.pesquisas').toggle(200);
    else $('.pesquisas').hide();
  })
});

$(function() {
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(a) {
    return function(e) {
      return ~$(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase());
    }
  });
  $("[name=q]").on("input", function() {
    $(".opcao").hide();
    $(".opcao:contains('" + this.value + "')").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.pesquisas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="q" class="search-text" placeholder="Procurar..." autocomplete="off" id="textFind">
<div class="pesquisas" id="pesquisas">
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Agenda</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Lista de clientes</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Lista de fornecedores</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Cadastrar novo fornecedor</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Lista de produtos</a>
  </div>
  <div class="opcao">
    <a>Cadastrar novo produto</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso só faltou definir um if pra executar apenas acima de 2 caracteres `if(string.length >= 2)` pq no seu snippet tá ocorrendo só na 1a letra pressionada, da 2a em diante não funciona...

Comment: Realmente tinha me esquecido de colocar essa condição. Vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, apesar de provavelmente estar fora do assunto, acredito que a sua ideia seja dar sugestões ao usuário a partir do preenchimento do input, eu mesmo já fiz algo parecido manualmente e ficou muito legal, mas depois de ter descoberto o `datalist`(Novo recurso do HTML5), só criaria uma dessas se eu quiser muito trabalhar o estilo, mas acredito que cabe a sugestão de usar uma `datalist`.

Exemplo:

```html
<input type=text list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.